# Server side push technology - After a database change

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, primefaces, websocket

I am working on `primefaces` datatable which has data from the database. This client side data is received  when the refresh button is hit. If there is a database change, the client doesn't know about it and has to refresh the page often.

I was looking for server side `push technology` and getting to know about `WebSocket`. However, I cant find or do not know how it will work in my situation. 
The database change is done through `Hibernate`. So how do I monitor the database change done by hibernate? and, after detection send that value to the client?
I am using Java and tomcat.

Comment: Recommend looking into the jBoss/Wildfly archetypes: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-wfk-quickstarts

Comment: You can use [entityListeners](http://mdshannan1.blogspot.nl/2011/06/how-to-use-jpa-hibernate-lifecycle.html) for monitoring changes/actions and use PF push to notify the frontend

Answer (score 0):

since you're using primefaces, you can use the p:poll widget to monitor the server side.

OR

you could leverage the primefaces support for atmosphere.

if you're just monitoring a small amount of changes, a poller would probably be the easier solution.  if you need to provide reactivity to a large number of changes, the pf-push and atmosphere framework will give you a good base to leverage.